# Programatically the best solution to determine if for loop can be run on object

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop, foreach, each

In research I am trying to find the fastest way to determine if a object has values and a for can be executed on the object.
**REF**: https://jsperf.com/jquery-each-vs-each-vs-for-loop/2

I used to do this, but in a discussion with a coworker he was using .each and we looked it up together and discovered that both methods are slow and in need of improvement.

```
if(Object.keys(X).length > 0) {
    // Execute For
}
```

Here is what I know:

```
obj instanceof Object
```

and

```
typeof(obj) == "object" and obj !== "null"
```

because null is an object, both have their draw backs, but perhaps there is another more superior method.

Comment: What about empty objects? Your codes will treat them differently. So what do you actually need?

Comment: Do you mean a `for in`,  `for of` or `for (i=0; i<…length; i++)` loop?

Comment: What's the harm in executing the loop on an empty list?

Answer (score 0):

A `for` loop can be executed on any object, so there is nothing to check here. Perhaps instead you need to consider what properties on the object you want to iterate, but that depends on the application.

Typically when iterating an object the code might look like:

```
for(var i in obj) {
    if(obj.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
        //do stuff here...
    }
}
```

The `hasOwnProperty` check ensures that you are only using values that were added to the object itself and not its prototype.